# React native play downloaded audio file offline through intent in mobile through google play music

Tags: android, json, react-native, android-intent, local-storage

Hello I am developing react native  audio app and I want to play downloaded audio files offline through external mobile default player google play music using intent. Please help !!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you already tried some potential solutions? In that case, it would be really helpful to add them to your post. Have you checked the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#send-intents-android) on intents?

Comment: Yes I have already searched in various resources but i could not find any useful output .